# Python & NumPy: Searching for the smallest value with a conditional (using a specific dtype)

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, where-clause

I'm working on an A* path finding algorithm in Python and have the data nicely tucked into a 2D NumPy array with this dtype:

```
numpy.dtype([
  ('open', bool),
  ('closed', bool),
  ('parent', object),
  ('g', int),
  ('f', int)
])
```

Following the [pseudo-code from Wikipedia's "A* search algorithm" entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Pseudocode), I need to interpret this:

```
current := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
```

This bit will give me the index of the lowest 'f' value (with the working array defined as pathArray):

```
numpy.unravel_index(numpy.argmin(pathArray['f']), pathArray['f'].shape)
```

...And this bit will find all the indexes where 'open' is True:

```
numpy.where(pathArray['open'])
```

How can I use these conditions together, finding the lowest 'f' value where 'open' is True?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `np.argmin` on `pathArray['f']`, you may want to use it on `pathArray[pathArray['open']]['f']`. Of course, you'll have to adapt the result so that you can use it with `pathArray['f']`...

---

An alternative consists in sorting `pathArray` along  the `'f'` field, then find the first entry for which `pathArray_sorted['open']` is `True.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with `numpy` but I still "think" this cannot be done using a build-in function. But I will still try to explain. What `Wikipedia` means is that you need something like a `priority queue` in order to do  this:

```
current := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
```

You will need to do this very fast and what I would suggest is build a binary heap and use it as your priority queue. This could be easily done in python. [This](http://pravin.insanitybegins.com/posts/binary-heaps-and-priority-queues) is a very good article that explains `heaps` and `priority queues` and their implementation in python.
Good luck